# Change Drop-Down Values Verbiage of PO Source (Drop-Ship, Purchase to Order)

Tags: acumatica

We would like to change the display text of the drop-down values on PO Source of SO line items to something like 'Drop-ship to Client' and 'Purchase for Inventory'.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the `PXStringListAttribute` attribute of the field with a customization.

Since it's only a localized label change you can also change it on the Translation Dictionaries page (SM200540).
[image]

Result:
[image]